# How to sort elements on DOM by its inner Text

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, graph

I have a graph that is rendering its values as a div inside the body element with a class according to their number values. This is working fine. But next I need to sort the divs according to their number values or background color. BUT, it needs to start on the lower left corner of the page and fan out upwards to towards the right as the numbers increase. Basically just like a line graph.

I'd like to stay away from libraries if at all possible.

How would I approach this? Thank you all.

```js
let interval = setInterval(makeDivs, 5);

function makeDivs(){
   let cont = checkHeight();
   if(cont){
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      let randNum = Math.random() * 100;
      if(randNum < 20) { div.classList.add('blue') }
      if(randNum >= 20 && randNum < 40) { div.classList.add('green') }
      if(randNum >= 40 && randNum < 60) { div.classList.add('yellow') }
      if(randNum >= 60 && randNum < 80) { div.classList.add('orange') }
      if(randNum >= 80 && randNum < 101) { div.classList.add('red') }
      div.textContent = randNum.toFixed(2);
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
   } else {
      alert('done');
      clearInterval(interval);
      sortDivs(); // Begin sorting divs
   }
}

function checkHeight(){
   let w = window.innerHeight;
   let b = document.querySelector('body').offsetHeight;
   if(b < w) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}

function sortDivs(){
   document.querySelector("body div:last-child").remove();
   alert('sorting now...')
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
body { width: 100vw; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: end;}
body div { width: calc(10% + 1px); text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; padding: 10px;}
body div.blue { background: aqua; }
body div.green { background: green; }
body div.yellow { background: yellow; }
body div.orange { background: orange; }
body div.red { background: red; }
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE!!!**

So I have this so far based on the feed back down below. The problem now is the sorting is only happening laterally and not on an angle (spreading right and to the top).

```js
let interval = setInterval(makeDivs, 10);

      function makeDivs(){
         let cont = checkHeight();
         if(cont){
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            let randNum = Math.random() * 100;
            if(randNum < 20) { div.classList.add('blue') }
            if(randNum >= 20 && randNum < 40) { div.classList.add('green') }
            if(randNum >= 40 && randNum < 60) { div.classList.add('yellow') }
            if(randNum >= 60 && randNum < 80) { div.classList.add('orange') }
            if(randNum >= 80 && randNum < 101) { div.classList.add('red') }
            div.textContent = randNum.toFixed(2);
            document.querySelector('.outPut').appendChild(div);
         } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.querySelector(".outPut div:last-child").remove();
            compileArrays(); // Begin sorting divs
         }
      }

      function checkHeight(){
         let w = window.innerHeight;
         let b = document.querySelector('.outPut').offsetHeight;
         if(b < w) {
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      }

      function compileArrays(){
         let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.outPut div');
         let bArr = [], gArr = [], yArr = [], oArr = [], rArr = [];
         divs.forEach( (d) => {
            if( d.classList.contains('blue') ){ bArr.push(d) }
            if( d.classList.contains('green') ){ gArr.push(d) }
            if( d.classList.contains('yellow') ){ yArr.push(d) }
            if( d.classList.contains('orange') ){ oArr.push(d) }
            if( d.classList.contains('red') ){ rArr.push(d) }
         });
         let finalArr = sortArray(bArr).concat(sortArray(gArr)).concat(sortArray(yArr)).concat(sortArray(oArr)).concat(sortArray(rArr));
         newDom(finalArr);
      }

      function sortArray(arr){
         let newArr = arr;
         newArr.sort( (a, b) => {
            return a.innerText - b.innerText;
         });
         return newArr;
      }

      function newDom(arr){
         let b = document.querySelector('.outPut');
         b.innerHTML = '';
         arr.reverse();
         arr.forEach((a) => {
            b.appendChild(a);
         });

      }
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; align-items: flex-end;}
body .outPut { flex: 1; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction:row-reverse; }
body .outPut div { width: calc(10% + 1px); text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; padding: 10px;}
body .outPut div.blue { background: aqua; }
body .outPut div.green { background: #44df15; }
body .outPut div.yellow { background: yellow; }
body .outPut div.orange { background: orange; }
body .outPut div.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="outPut"></div>
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using HTML for that. Consider using a `<canvas>` or SVG DOM. Also, converting text to numbers is inefficient. Why not store the value as a number in JS.

Comment: Why no HTML? Speed and performance is not an issue for this, just need it to work properly above everything else.

Comment: so after creating an ordered data array, you want to determine the div's placement based on the distance from the bottom left corner? sounds like something that could be done with absolute CSS positioning

Comment: @MaloPavol I added an image showing how id like it to look like when its done sorting. Hope this clarifies a little more.

Comment: Interesting problem. Canvas would be a better suited for your task both for speed and design. Also I would STRONGLY recommend a for loop rather than recursive setInterval. For grid based layouts use [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) over flexbox. Here's my canvas based solution:  https://codepen.io/kaleidawave/pen/oNjXVjv

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you already have a mechanism to organise such DIVs in a grid as shown, the following should give you what you are looking for:

```
var items = divList.filter((div) => div.nodeType == 1); // get rid of the whitespace text nodes

items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
      ? 0
      : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});
```

Then, place them back in the DOM as needed, example:

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  divList.appendChild(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ellias I updated my original post using some of your approach. Now im stuck in the way the sorting spreads. Its spreading from the bottom left corner but only laterally, I need it to go also upwards as well (45deg angle)

Comment: I don't think it is possible without a considerable added complexity. Perhaps you should consider canvases as suggested above for a cleaner and more maintainable solution

Answer (score 0):

**This worked with the first code example!!!**

try this sortDivs function:

```
function sortDivs() {
    document.querySelector("body div:last-child").remove();
    alert('sorting now...')

    let toSort = document.getElementsByTagName("div")

    toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort, 0)
    toSort.sort((a, b) => {
        let aord = parseFloat(a.textContent);
        let bord = parseFloat(b.textContent);
        return bord - aord;
    })

    document.body.innerHTML = ""

    for(var i = 0, l = toSort.length; i < l; i++) {
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(toSort[i]);
    }
}
```

and in the css file set flex-wrap to wrap-reverse. Hope I could help :)

> PS: please, implement some **else if** instead of doing only **if**

Comment: I modified my original post. Now im stuck in the way the sorting spreads. Its spreading from the bottom left corner but only laterally, I need it to go also upwards as well (45deg angle)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small fiddle with my sample code demonstrating a simple solution in pure JavaScript and absolute CSS positioning for what you are trying to achieve. [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/MaloPavol/djrn4fqt/57/)

As some pointed out already, there might be a library, that already provides a better and complete solution for this - I did not research if it is so.

Code:

file.js

```
var container = document.getElementById("container")

var results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

//you can pre-calculate the order of the distances
//here already orderdered array [distanec][X-axis][Y-axis]
var distances =[[0,0,0],
                [1,1,0],
                [1,0,1],
                [1.414, 1,1],
                [2,0,2],
                [2,2,0],
                [2.234, 2,1],
                [2.234, 1,2]]


for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div")
  newDiv.className = "result"
  newDiv.innerHTML = results[i]
  newDiv.style.left = distances[i][1]*20 + "px"
  newDiv.style.bottom = distances[i][2]*20 + "px"
  container.appendChild(newDiv)

}


function setColor(element){
 // set class based on value - you already have this part
}
```

style.css

```
#container {
  border: 4px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.result{
  border: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

site.html

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Output:

[image]